# Decoding cyclic code, assuming we have no errors

Tags: error-correcting-codes

Assuming the coded data is errorless and given generator polynomial coefficients. By what algorithm can I decode the data coded by matrix constructed by given generator polynomial?

Comment: Have you checked your course material?  Or do you mean there should be a faster algorithm assuming the coded data is errorless?

Comment: main problem is that generator matrix is irreversible(as it is not square) so i am confused how to revert coded word to it's original meaning. "assuming the code is errorless" is by problem declaration, that i am trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with generator matrix $G$, a matrix of $k$ rows and $n$ columns where $n\ge k$. Given any input row vector $s$ of $k$ characters, we can generate the codeword for $s$, a row vector of $n$ entries by 
$$w=sG$$
If given $s$, how can we get back $w$? Suppose we can find a matrix $G'$ of $n$ rows and $k$ columns such that 
$$GG'=I_k$$
where $I_k$ is the identity matrix of $k$, we will have 
$$s=sI_k=s(GG')=(sG)G'=wG'$$

So the question becomes how to find such matrix $G'$ from $G$. You should be able to find in your course material the procedure or technique to accomplish that. Note that $G'$ is not a square matrix. In general $G'$ is not unique, either.

Now suppose you are given a generator polynomial instead. You can form the generator matrix from the generator polynomial and proceed as above. There might be a shortcut procedure for generator polynomial because of its special form.

Comment: yeah, the main problem is dividing the codeword by generator matrix(that has no inverse)

Comment: Do you mean the main problem is how to find the matrix $G'$? Note that $w$ is obtained by multiplying $w$, the coded word with $G'$. There is no "dividing" here.

Comment: I mean: multiplying with G' is "division" with G

Comment: We can find $G'$ by an established method that involves no "dividing" by a matrix. Is dividing by a scalar needed? Yes. (In fact, dividing by a scalar can be done by multiplication by a scalar.)

Comment: _You should be able to find in your course material the procedure or technique that finds $G'$._